# Deploying only modified files with TeamCity?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have an ASP.NET web site - aka, I don't need to build the project and deploy dlls along with the project, I just place the .aspx and .aspx.cs files on my web server and things are compiled automatically.

I would like to setup TeamCity as a continuous integration server for this project so that it will only deploy the files that were checked in rather than updating every file in the project when I leave a specifically formatted comment during checkin.

So far I was able to setup a build trigger that only fires if the comment is formatted correctly, but I can't find a way to tell TeamCity to only deploy the files that have been checked in rather than the entire project.

Can this be done?  If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Microsoft's [**WebDeploy**](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy). It will automatically deploy only the files that have changed.

Troy Hunt's guide to setting up build and deployment in Team City along with WebDeploy is an excellent place to start:

http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html

Also, if you prefer a more manual approach, you could use **RoboCopy** to do a sync:

http://itbloggertips.com/2013/05/robocopy-command-copy-only-new-changed-files-sync-both-the-drive/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, man even TeamCity people them selves have no idea about this.